# Cache busting Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, caching, cache-control

My App Service is correctly updated. But i dont see the UI from the first enter.
I use Angular and Azure App Service for this.

If i put F5(without Ctrl) it reloads and gives me the right view of UI.
But after near 1 hour situation returns the same. I come to App and it is still with old view.

To avoid caching i used this:
Adding to index.html meta tags:

```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
```

Adding outputHasing in angular.json production setup

```
"outputHashing": "all"
```

Before publishing to Azure i built project by this command (but i am not sure i am doing it right, other users supposed to use it inside azure app probably, i tried by Kudu CMD but i didn't get success there)

```
ng build --prod --aot --outputHashing=all
```

Comment: are you trying to update the UI for users that already opened the app, but you want to do it at the moment new version of app is deployed? Or is there indeed something cached, and you get old sources after opening the page at some point?

Comment: @Andrei I want to update interface for users who have already entered before in App and they probably have some js bundle generated by angular build which has the same name as before update(thats why i suppose it is not working).
BUT after every hour my old version returns and one more time i have to reload by F5.

Comment: wording in the question doesn't sound like a cache. But if you are sure it is cache - ensure you are NOT caching index.html. it is very small and will be downloaded in no time, but it will contain a different link to main.[hash].js each time